# SqlCeException in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I have been using Microsoft Live API for uploading & downloading database. but after downloading or uploading if i tried to access the database in anyway my app gives SqlCeException Unhandled & exits.
If i restart the app before accessing database it doesn't give any errors so for now the solution is

Restart the application

This is my code

```
    IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = null;

    private void Upload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (client == null || client.Session == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You Must Sign In First.");
        }
        else
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure? This Will Overwrite Your Old Backup File!", "Backup?", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                UploadDatabase();
            }
        }
    }

    public void UploadDatabase()
    {
        if (SDFolderID != string.Empty)
        {
            WLInfo.Text = "Uploading Backup...";

            this.client.UploadCompleted += new EventHandler<LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs>(ISFile_UploadCompleted);

            try
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    fileStream = store.OpenFile("DB.sdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    client.UploadAsync(SDFolderID, "DB.sdf", fileStream, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
                    WLInfo.Text = "Upload Complete.";
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                WLInfo.Text = "Error: Restart Application.";
            }
        }
    }

    private void ISFile_UploadCompleted(object sender, LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Error == null)
        {
            client = new LiveConnectClient(session);
            client.GetCompleted += new EventHandler<LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs>(GetFiles_GetCompleted);
            client.GetAsync(SDFolderID + "/files");
        }
        else
        {
            this.WLInfo.Text = "Error Uploading Backup File.";
        }
        fileStream.Close();
    }

    void GetFiles_GetCompleted(object sender, LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<object> data = (List<object>)e.Result["data"];

        foreach (IDictionary<string, object> content in data)
        {
            if (((string)content["name"]).Equals(FileName))
            {
                FileID = (string)content["id"];
            }
        }

        if (FileID != null)
        {
            WLInfo.Text = "Backup Found On Sky Drive.";
        }
        else
        {
            WLInfo.Text = "Backup Not Found On Sky Drive.";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's probably of a Stream not properly closed so your database file is still locked. When you upload or download your database file make sure you use the using statement on all disposable object so that all the Stream are properly disposed automatically

In your code fileStream is not disposed which is probably what is causing the problem (you should "save" this variable in a local filed and call dispose on it in ISFile_UploadCompleted).

Also when if you use `using` there is no need to call dispose on the object (no need to have `store.Dispose();`, it's automatically done when you go out of the using scope)

Comment: Can you update your code with the change you made just to be sure

Comment: Also you have to make sure you are not accessing the database during the upload

Comment: (you could for example do a local copy of the database and upload from the copy instead)

Comment: any suggestions about creating local copy of the database or something to refer?

Comment: but i guess if i copy the file then maybe its name should be change & then my downloading database code which is working need to be change

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37606/discussion-between-xsheru-and-benoit-catherinet)